# Remove Fields from Custom Content Query Web Part

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I created a custom content query web part where I just want to display one field (Description).

How do I get rid of the fields for Link, Image, SipAddress, LinkToolTip, OpenInNewWindow, and Title?  I just want to simplify my custom web part and just have the Description field showing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Edit the Content Query web part .
- Get the selected Custom Style Name at Presetnation > Style > Item Style.
- via SharePoint Designer > Open your Root site.
- Go to all files > `Style library` > `XSL Style Sheets` > `ItemStyle.xml`
- Create a copy from `ItemStyle.xml` to allow rollback then > Edit it as advanced mode.

[image]

- Find the currently selected item style name > check the Variables and styles that corresponded to your fields in your custom style > remove it.
- Save > Check In > Publish as Major Version.
- After you finish > go to your QCWP > Edit it > and select your custom style from Presentation > Styles > Item Style > it'should be now removed.

[image]

**[Suggestion]**

Instead of modifying the current item style I suggest to you to create a new item style as the following:

- Paste the following code at the end of `ItemStyle.xml` file before `</xsl:stylesheet>`
- Change the style `class="item link-item"` as your old one

> ```
>    <xsl:template name="DiscOnly" match="Row[@Style='DiscOnly']" mode="itemstyle">
>
>
>         <div class="item link-item">
>             <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
>
>             <div class="description">
>                 <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </xsl:template>
> ```

Save > Check In > Publish as Major Version.
- After you finish > go to your QCWP > Edit it > and select your custom style from Presentation > Styles > Item Style > the OutPut should be like this.

[image]